# Most efficient way to create bulk new shifted weighted average columns in a pandas datframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe which I am trying to setup to use in some regression analysis:

```
Date        Person     Feature1  Feature2 ....  Feature100
1/1/2020      Jim         12        15               82
1/7/2020      Jim         1         25               84
1/1/2021      Jim         12        15               85
1/1/2020      Jan         1         35               86
1/7/2020      Jan         5         15               84
1/1/2021      Jan         14        5               82
```

I have created a list of some of the columns I would like to transform (about 50 columns):

```
l = ['Feature1','Feature2',......'Feature58']
```

For each of columns names found in `l` I would like to create a weighted average of each persons last 20 entries (weighted to the most recent) and shifted by 1 (because I hope to use it as a predicition feature).

```
Date        Person     Feature1  Feature2 ....  Feature100   Feature1_Shifted    Feature2_Shifted ... Feature58_Shifted
1/1/2020      Jim         12        15               82        N/A               N/A
1/7/2020      Jim         1         25               84        12               15
1/1/2021      Jim         12        15               85        6.5              20
1/1/2020      Jan         1         35               86        N/A              N/A
1/7/2020      Jan         5         15               84        1                35
1/1/2021      Jan         14        5               82         3                25
```

Loosly based off this quesition here: [Most Pythonic Way to Create Many New Columns in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35180846/most-pythonic-way-to-create-many-new-columns-in-pandas)

and for the weighted average here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57602282/13194245 with the option of changing the weightings.

I am struggling to combine everything into one (and where to start). So any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The answer on calculating weighted average you linked to uses a numpy function that requires specific weights specified for each value.  Pandas has another function for calculating exponential (decaying) weighted averages: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html.  Is that what you are hoping to implement?  Or will you have weights defined in their own column?

Comment: That looks like it could be a good option! I havent defined any weights in their own columns so that sounds like it will work!

Comment: Hi @AlexK. Do you know if you can set a window period with `ewm`? it doesnt look like you can?

Comment: See if the link I provided helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the exponential decay approach is acceptable to you, there is actually already a post that should help you: [Create a rolling custom EWMA on a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38836482/9987623).  The second (not accepted) answer implements a custom function to allow rolling EWM operations over a specified window.

To get it to work with your list of columns, you would just replace the last line of that code with:

```
l.append('Person')
ewm_df = df[l].groupby('Person').rolling(window).apply(ewma).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
```

where `l` is your list of columns.  If you want to add '_shifted' to each column name, `rename` should help as a last step:

```
ewm_df.rename({col: col + '_shifted' for col in l}, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

The window will be 20 in your case.

***EDIT***

I am not yet sure how to add the results to the original df using the code already provided.  You would need a merge key besides "Person" in the `ewm_df` dataframe and then merge the two dfs on two keys.  My workaround would be to create new columns in the original dataframe one by one:

```
for col in l:
  df[f"{col}_shifted"] = df.groupby('Person')[col].rolling(window).apply(ewma).values
```

***EDIT 2***

Since there is a custom function used, the shift operation can be done separately at the end:

```
for col in l:
   df[f"{col}_shifted"] = df.groupby('Person')[f"{col}_shifted"].shift()
```

***EDIT 3***

Okay, this whole thing requires a more involved statement.  The statement below will add the new shifted columns to the original dataframe.  I tested this statement on a simple mean (replacing `ewma` with `np.mean`) and it works.

```
for col in l:
   df[f"{col}_shifted"] = df.groupby('Person')[col].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(20).apply(ewma).shift())
```

Comment: Thanks! I was playing around with `ewm` weightings and found the Center of Mass (`com`) arguement was best set at `2.5`. So in this solution i would need to adjust the 'alpha` arguement somehow? Outside of this, looks like a great option

Comment: and also can i add an `_shifted` to the newly created column name?

Comment: @SOK Updated the answer to add this suffix to each new column.

Comment: Thanks, i seem to be getting a key error with `Person`. Is the line `ewm_df = df[l].groupby('Person')` removing person from the `df`?

Comment: Yep, added a line to add 'Person' to the same list.

Comment: There is a formula for `com` in [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html) that maps `alpha` to `com`, so you should be able to derive the `alpha` value from that.

Comment: Is there any way to add the columns to the existing df?

Comment: @SOK I added a workaround for creating new columns in the original df.  If I think of a better way, I'll add it.

Comment: Looks great - only thing is the `window` function seems to be applying to every row and not the specific group. Appreciate your help with this!

Comment: This is great, thanks so much for all of your help